# how to add filters in shop page in twenty sixteen theme

Tags: wordpress, filter

I wanted to add filter in shop page using twenty sixteen theme

I try to add filter in sidebar from widget but it is  not working.

please help me.
below is the link

https://www.dev.bulldesing.com/shop/

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is it you want?  this is the default filter also you can add sidebar using the custom template with this theme [image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Shakil. Actually I want to add side bar into shop page and add attribute filter in sidebar which display on shop page but when I try to add sidebar form widget it is not working or not change anything

Comment: you need to add a custom template with sidebar if default one is not working